# api.search parameters for time of tweet and number of tweets

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to collect tweets using certain hashtags using the twitter api and the tweepy module.  I know how to get the 15 most recent tweets using a given hashtag using the code below:

```
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key=con_key, consumer_secret=con_secret)
auth.set_access_token(acc_token, acc_secret)

#Connect to the Twitter API using the authentication
api = tweepy.API(auth)

tweet_list = api.search(q = '#23squadgoals')
```

However I was wondering what parameters I use to specify the number of the tweets to return.  Also is there a parameter I can use to specify the timing? Like what I want to collect tweets that were tweeted a week ago?

ANy help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Anyone interested?

Comment: It is not possible, only the most recent tweets are available for collecting.